# d3. Calling a csv url from an array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv, url, d3.js

I'm new at this. Im trying to make a simple interactive chart  using jaavascript. The idea is that when I change the values in the selector, the chart change the data is using.

However, I´m having troubles with the data switching. The data come´s frome different urls. Those urls are in a CSV file. My code extracts the urls from th CSV file and makes an array. Then it proceed to call the CSV file from the adequate element of the array. Simplifying the code:

```
functionThatReturnsArray(){
d3.csv("http//URL.COM", function(){
SomeMoreCode;
return ArrayOfStrings
};)
}

A = functionThatReturnsArray();

MoreCode;

//For example, the first value from A is selected
d3.csv(A[0], function(error, data) {
MoreCode;
})
```

The problem is that it seems that this isn´t a valid input to d3.csv, because it doesn´t work. I don´t know if i´m missing something or it just can´t be done this way.

I searched and it might be from the fact that d3.csv is an asynchronous method, but I´m not sure if that´s the problem.

Any suggestion will be apreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first `CSV` data is loading asynchronously, so this function will not return anything

```
functionThatReturnsArray(){
   d3.csv("http//URL.COM", function(){
       SomeMoreCode;
       return ArrayOfStrings
   };)
}
```

You can put following code in function

```
function processArray(A){

   MoreCode;

   //For example, the first value from A is selected
   d3.csv(A[0], function(error, data) {
   MoreCode;
  })
}
```

and invoke this function in first `csv` loading callback

```
 functionThatReturnsArray(){
       d3.csv("http//URL.COM", function(){
           SomeMoreCode;
           processArray(ArrayOfStrings) //add this
       };)
 }
```